# How to send data using jquery ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a novice to ajax and want to know how to send data using jquery ajax method, any help will really be appreciated. 
This is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script>
        function show(str){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#games").change(function(){
                    valcc = $("#games").val();
                    $("#div1").load("gg.php");
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="games" name="games" onchange="show(this.value)">
        <option value="cricket">cricket</option>
        <option value="soccer">soccer</option>
        <option value="chess">chess</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="button" id="button" />
    <div id="dd">Please select a Game</div>
    <div id="div1" style="width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid  #999;"></div>
```

I need to send the value of select option to the gg.php page and then procees it.
Please help

Comment: `$("#div1").load("gg.php?valcc="+valcc);`? And then use `$_GET['valcc']` in `gg.php` page

Comment: Refer this **[LINK](http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this function `onchange` of the select input.

```
function show(str)
{
$.ajax({
        type:'post',    // the type of request POST,GET etc
        url:'gg.php',   //  url to which request is send
        datatype:'html',  // datatype like html,text,json etc
        data:'games='+str, // pass the data; if there are multiple parameters you have to append it like data:'param1='+val1+'&param2='+val2 etc
        success:function(response)  // on success get response
        {

        }
    });
}
```

Now you can process the data passed through the ajax in *gg.php*. As you are passing the data through `POST`, you have to access the value as

```
$value=$_POST['games'];  // index as the parameter name passed through ajax
```

Note: Whatever you echo in the gg.php will be send as response to the ajax function.

For example,

In the ajax response, alert the response.

```
function show(str)
{
   .............
   success:function(response)  // on success get response
    {
       alert(response);
    }
}
```

Now try to echo the games value in gg.php,

```
<?php
echo $value=$_POST['games'];
exit;
?>
```

Now you can understand clearly the working of ajax.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time and help, i am really honored,

Comment: Right i will do it, this is my first day here so i m quite confussed

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using jQuery so its very easy

You can do something like this, first you dont need onchange="show(this.value)".

```
$(function(){
   $("#games").on("change", function(){
      var gameData =  $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "gg.php",
        data: { game: gameData  }
        })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
   });
});
```

At gg.php you can get this value by $_POST['game'];

for more info on AJAX visit http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.i m glad i am here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put the doc ready block in a function like that and you can use `$.get()` ajax method to send values and get the response. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#games").change(function(){
       var valcc = $(this).val(); // get the current value of selected
       $.get("gg.php", {data: valcc}, function(resp){ // pass that in a object
           $("#div1").html(resp); // place the comming response html
       });
   });
});
```

---

You can takeout this inline script `onchange="show(this.value)"`.